# Finding sf::Text width before drawing?

Tags: c++, sfml

text.getLocalBounds().width only works after the text has been drawn, and the code structure I'm working with doesn't allow for that. I'm going to rearrange the program a bit, but I was wondering if there was a way to estimate it regardless.

Comment: This was fixed after 2.1 was released. 2.2 is to be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the local bounds

```
    sf::Text infoText;
    infoText.setPosition(0.0f, SCREEN_Y-23.0f);
    infoText.setCharacterSize(20);
    infoText.setString("press i for info");
    infoText.setFont(*resourceManager()->getFont(ResourceManager::FontResources::sansation_ttf));

    std::cout << "info text width: " <<  infoText.getLocalBounds().width << std::endl;
```

I am able to get the correct width every time.  My version of SFML is a little beyond 2.1, because I required an extra feature.  What version of SFML are you using?

I am using SFML from this commit: 29c0f1491177d9125cc731f0c04bdf4c21c4650e